# open the link in new window in crystal report 11

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

I also have the same problem of opening the link in the new window.

There is the hyperlink column in the report.. I want to open that link in new window.

Here is the sample link:

www.facerek.com

This link will be dynamic according to the column value, So there is the code written in formula field

IF x=1 then "www.facerek.com/abcd=" &{TC.ID}
ELSE
"www.facerek.com/efg=" &{TC.ID}

I am using crystal 11.

How can I can achieve this?